# Use regex to add extra single quote in string so that it passes dynamically

Tags: regex, oracle

I am passing string below splitting it into columns.
However i need to make it dynamic such that in addition to existing regex there is condition that the single quotes inside text get doubled up, so that any string passed, **we dont have to manually add extra quote** and it gets passed dynamically.

```
SELECT 110, 'At's the get', 1,
                regexp_substr('At's the get',
                '("[^"]*"|[^, "]+)', 1, 1, null, 1) result
           FROM dual  --actual string
```

This will later be used in a procedure so that we pass a string at runtime with single quotes, so regex adds to the quotes and string is passed dynamically.

Comment: if you use the above in procedure, then you will be forced to use a variable. The variable will hold the correct value (as long as you assign it a correct value) -so, no need for the quote replacing. Try running your query with variables to see this for yourself `SELECT 110, :mystring, 1,    regexp_substr(:mystring, '("[^"]*"|[^, "]+)', 1, 1, null, 1) result  FROM dual`

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't . have tried in proc and it throws error

Comment: I am using oracle 12c/12.1

Comment: take a look here please: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d7981b63e799ffe8c7008842667303f9

Comment: The procedure at the end. have passed sample string

Answer (score 1):

So when you call your procedure you should use `''` (two quotes) instead of `'` (just one quote).
This does not mean that the string will contain two single quotes, you are just [escaping](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/quotes.php) single quote character.

Any way your procedure call should look like this:

```
begin 
push_data(120,'"Alphabet''s are not limited", "Limits"');
end;
/
```

And then

```
SELECT * FROM push_data_temp;
```

gives the result:

```
    ID_PK   ID  COL1                             COL2   COL3    COL4    COL5    COL6    COL7    COL8    COL9    COL10   COL11   COL12 

       1    120 "Alphabet's are not limited"    "Limits"
```

Comment: that is exactly what i can't do. I know we can add extra quote to avoid but i am looking for modifying the procedure such that at runtime we dont have to modify the string

Comment: @Vini and how exactly are you going to feed the string to the procedure ? If the string is typed in - like in your example above then escaping in mandatory.  if you read the string from table into variable - then you have no problem to begin with. I thing you are confusing the actual sting contents and the escape characters for the interpreter ....

Comment: actually the string will be coming from an array to procedure, so it will directly get passed during calling time. which is why i need to amend procedure to replace single quote with double

Comment: @Vini which is exactly why you should do no such thing. Amusing someone else is filling the array (from whatever source) -  If stings are already in the array - your procedure should run AS IS without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

In an SQL or PL/SQL **string literal**, to get one single-quote in the string you must put two single-quotes next to each other in the text of the literal. The language then translates those two single-quotes into one single-quote which is put into the string. When you print this string out there will only be one single-quote. This is built into the language and there's no way around it. Note that this ONLY applies to **string literals** in the text of a program. If you read a string from a file or from a table in the database which has a one single-quote in it you'll get one single-quote, and if you print it out only one single-quote will be printed.

However, if you're absolutely adamant that you shouldn't/can't/won't put two apostrophes next to one another to get one in your string you can use the `CHR` function to put an apostrophe into the string using string concatenation. The ASCII code for an apostrophe is 39, so if you execute

```
SELECT 'Here' || CHR(39) || 's an apostrophe' FROM DUAL
```

you'll get

```
Here's an apostrophe
```

Look, ma - no doubled-up single-quotes!